# JavaScript: What is addEventListener?

Tags: javascript

What is this function? Didn't really find any good examples.

Comment: The first link Google gave me was a pretty good example...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: `Didn't really find any good examples.` ... Did you look?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `addEventListener` method is the [W3C standard method](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-registration) to attach an event handler to an element, so that you can do something useful when an event is triggered. The following example would popup an alert message when the element with id `my_image_id` is clicked:

```
function doSomething() {
   alert('Image clicked');
}

var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id');

myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
```

Unfortunately this does not work in Internet Explorer, since Microsoft uses a different event registration model. In Internet Explorer 5+, you would have to attach the event handler as follows:

```
myImage.attachEvent('onclick', doSomething);
```

Therefore for a cross browser event registration method, you can use reflection and execute conditionally:

```
function addEventHandler(node, type, f) {
   if (node.addEventListener) {
      node.addEventListener(type, f, false);
   } 
   else if (node.attachEvent) {
      node.attachEvent("on" + type, f);
   } 
   else {
      node["on" + type] = f;
   }
}

var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id');

addEventHandler(myImage, 'click', doSomething);
```

Further reading:

- [Mozilla Dev Center: element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)
- [Quirksmode: Advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)
- [Douglas Crockford: The Theory of the DOM](http://www.javascriptworkshop.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/AnInconvenientAPI.pdf)

Comment: daniel, When does `node["on" + type] = f;`come to use. Aren't the prior two cases sufficient???

Comment: Daniel,
But Not working for me either in Chrome or IE.
Do I need a framework to use this function???

For that to work I had to add `onload="addEventHandler(this, 'click', doSomething);"` in that tag to add a `click` event on that element.

Answer (score 6):

You may be familiar with adding an event handler like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  alert('onload event!');
};
```

or even in HTML like this:

```
<body onload="alert('onload event!')">
```

Well, the downside to this is that you can only have one event handler.  So if something else later overwrites that "onload" property, the previous event handler is no longer used.

**addEventListener** is a way to register an event handler without overwriting a previous one.  It's supported by most browsers other than Internet Explorer.  No to worry, though, because Internet Explorer has its own equivalent: **attachEvent**.

Here's a (simplified) example of their use:

```
        if (myelement.addEventListener) {
            // other browsers
            myelement.addEventListener(eventname, callback, false);
        } 
        else {
            myelement.attachEvent("on"+eventname, callback);
        }
```

It's usually a better idea to register an event using addEventListener or attachEvent methods than the onload/onsomething property because it will not possibly disrupt any other Javascript code from the same page.

Comment: thumbs up for explaining why we use it, not just what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The `addEventListener()` method attaches an event handler to an element without overwriting existing event handlers. Like "click" or "DOMContentLoaded". It is *listening* for some event to happen. Then you add some function that it will execute when that event happens

For Example:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("div").style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```