# How to add ondblclick on an image with Javascript in a loop?

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Event handlers inside a Javascript loop - need a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341723/event-handlers-inside-a-javascript-loop-need-a-closure)

```
for i = 1 to 5
{
 var el = document.createElement('img');
 el.ondblclick = somefunction();
 mydiv.appendChild(el);
}
```

Seems el.ondblclick = somefunction('test'); doesn't do any insertion.

I know I can do..

```
el.ondblclick= function() { somefunction('test') };
```

.. but that doesn't work in a loop!

Comment: What does it do instead? Any errors?

Comment: Your loop has some strange Pascal syntax. See the JS syntax here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080/how-do-i-build-a-loop-in-javascript

Comment: Any chance you're using `i` inside the function?

Comment: Maybe you should look into using jQuery and similar libraries. It really makes event handling a lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) // initialization, condition, loop step
{
    var el = document.createElement('img');
    // you do not want to call `somefunction`, but refer to it:
    el.ondblclick = somefunction;
    mydiv.appendChild(el);
}
```

If your problem is, that you want to use `i` inside the callback function:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var el = document.createElement('img');
    el.ondblclick = (function(i) { // bind i
        return function() { // return closure
            toggleClass('svg_container_' + i);
        };
    })(i);
    mydiv.appendChild(el);
}
```

C.f.

- [How do I build a loop in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52080/how-do-i-build-a-loop-in-javascript)
- [JavaScript: What is addEventListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695793/javascript-what-is-addeventlistener)
- [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Problem is to do this: el.ondblclick= function() { toggleClass('svg_container_'+i) - i will be 6 and not value of i in the loop.

Comment: @Akyhne: Kay's second code sample should work perfectly for you; just replace `somefunction(i)` with `toggleClass('svg_container_'+i)`.

Comment: Updated to your example (but @apsillers was faster than me :-) )

Comment: It does actually, after some fiddling with the code! Isn't there a more easy way though? Seems like a lot of code for so little.

Comment: jQuery: `$('img').on('click', function() { $(this).toggleClass('someclass'); }).appendTo(mydiv)`. And you'd have even less to write using RightJS.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't be more complicated than this: el.ondblclick = somefunction();

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know I had to. I thought clicking the "This was usefull" would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code. I personally hate when people don't post a working example

```
        var sCurMonthId = sMonthId.substr(4, 2);
        var cellRight = oCurRow.insertCell(-1);
        cellRight.colSpan = iNumCells;
        for (svg = 1; svg < iNumCells; svg++)
        {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = 'svg_container';
            div.id = 'svg_container_'+svg+'_'+sMonthId;
            cellRight.appendChild(div);
            var el = document.createElement('img');
            el.style.width = svg == 5 ? '99.5%' : '49%';
            el.className = 'svg_chart';
            el.style.cssFloat = svg%2 == 0 ? 'right' : 'left';
            el.ondblclick = (function(svg) {
                return function() {
                    toggleClass('svg_container_'+svg+'_'+sMonthId, 'svg_container', 'svg_expanded');
            };
    })(svg);
            el.src = 'mySite.tld';
            div.appendChild(el);
        }
```