# i need to create an event listener. but i dont want to use any framework

Tags: javascript

i need to create an event listener. but i dont want to use any framework

**Jquery:**

```
$(".element").on('click', function(){});
```

How to make it without jquery???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Incidentally, jQuery is a library, not a framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: What is addEventListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695793/javascript-what-is-addeventlistener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to create an EventListener without JQuery...

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.element'), function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Your code
  }, false);
});
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

This article is also interesting: http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/63383858003/how-to-forget-about-jquery-and-start-using-native

Comment: No need for a downvote. It has some overhead with the `foreach`. You do not need that to add event listeners, however this does mimic the OP's sample completely.

Comment: @tomloprod, I mis-read. so probably the foreach as noted by Mouser.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`element.addEventListener(...)` method](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/element.addEventListener.html):

```javascript
var el = document.getElementById("foo");   
el.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("You clicked on 'foo'.");
}, false);
```

Note that various specifications allow you to select elements in various ways (e.g. [`getElementsByClassName(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName), [`getElementsByTagName(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName), etc).